# wordpress post status inquery

Tags: post-status

I am working on a local server to create wordpress website. I check in database every post which i made after publish its create 2 post in database. One with Inherit post status second with publish status and both have different post ID's.

I need to know its some kind of wordpress function or my mistake. and what is the benefit of Inherit post.

**How to solve it to make only publish post?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called as Revision in Wordpress.

Whenever you update your post, the older content of that post is treated as Revision and a new record for revision is inserted in posts table.

And we can check our revisions from Revision meta box.

More detail : https://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions

For - How to solve it to make only publish post?

You can define the number of revision you want to create and also can disable revision for wp posts by adding below lines in wp-config.php

`define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3 );` // max 3 revision will be stored.

`define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );` // disable revision system